# Does Necromage still boost spells vampires cast on themselves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

Does the Necromage perk still grant a bonus to spells active/cast on yourself as a Vampire? I read somewhere today that this "exploit" was patched and that Necromage doesn't offer the same benefits to Vampires as it used too. I'm running the latest patch 1.9.32.0.8.

My Restoration skill isn't quite high enough to test this for myself yet.

Comment: IIRC, this was "patched" out in the unofficial patch mods, but not in the base game.

Comment: @Affine that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unmodded Skyrim, Necromage still boosts some [spells and perks](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Necromage_(Perk)) when you are a vampire.

However, this has been patched in the unofficial skyrim patch.

Howeverx2, there are mods you can download to 'unfix' the patch if you really wanted the necromage boost.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the Unofficial Skyrim Patch. The idea of Necromage seems great but I hate cheating. Now I'm in two minds whether I should use it or not. Since it's the vampire benefits aren't disabled by the official patch I'm going to assume that it's okay and fair to use.